Which European country first introduced wristwatches to China and why is it called 手表?
As a native French speaker studying Mandarin Chinese, I couldn't help but notice that the Chinese term for wristwatch, 手表 (hand-show), is quite similar to the French term "une montre" (a "shower"/display). After further inspection, I notice that other European languages' term are quite different. All of Spanish, Portuguese and German have a term that translates roughly to "arm clock" and English it's "watch".
Is the term 手表 actually originated from French or is it a pure coincidence? Was it French who introduced wristwatches to China, and if so, why France and not Chinese colonizers such as the United Kingdom or Portugal?

Might be a better fit for the Linguistics stack

@SPavel - ... or the Chinese Language SE. I do have to wonder if there's some reference for Chinese similar to the OED. If so, this would be a slam-dunk question over there.

I didn't find any promising info on a quick search, but I did discover that orginally they were called (in English?) "bracelet watches", and mostly used by women (who presumably had no pockets for pocket watches. Damn you fashion designers!)

Posted on linguistics: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/49468/why-is-wristwatch-in-chinese-called-%e6%89%8b%e8%a1%a8

@T.E.D. - Yes, and apparently they were considered a bit effeminate until WWI officers realised how inconvenient to was to have to delve into your clothes to check your watch.

"why France and not Chinese colonizers such as the United Kingdom or Portugal?" France did have colonies/concessions in China.

Each character in Chinese can mean many different things. In this context, your translation of 表 as "show" is not correct. (For example, 表哥 does not translate as "show elder brother".)
Here with 手表, 表 was originally from 圭表, which was a sort of ancient sundial for telling the seasons.
And in 圭表, 表 referred to the gnomon:

An object such as a pillar or a rod that is used to tell time by the shadow it casts when the sun shines on it, especially the pointer on a sundial.

Today, 表 can refer to any measurement device, hence also 电表 (electricity meter), 水表 (water meter), 钟表 ("bell meter"--or clock or watch), and 手表 ("hand meter"--or watch).
https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%A1%A8/

I couldn't find anything that suggests the introduction of wristwatches to China was a markedly "historical" event, unlike the introduction of European astronomical techniques to the Chinese imperial courts by Jesuit missionaries. I suspect wristwatches just diffused into China as part of global trade towards the end of the 19th century, rather than being introduced by colonisation.

As for 「表」 in the word 「手表」, that is highly unlikely to be a calque from a European language.
「手表」 is a Simplified Chinese rendering of the orthodox spelling 「手錶」, where 「錶」 (note the additional 「金」 component, meaning metal) was likely invented to specialise 「表」 to mean time-keeping device, by means of similarities to the word rendered as 「鐘表」 (striking clock; 「鐘」 means bell).
In the context of a measurement device, 「表」 is a morpheme roughly equivalent to English ~meter (e.g. thermometer) or ~graph (e.g. chronograph). This morpheme is ancient; even in the narrow sense of time-keeping devices, it is found in received texts dating back from BCE. From Master Lü's Spring and Autumn Annals:

《呂氏春秋・功名》
由其道，功名之不可得逃，猶表之與影，若呼之與響。
An orthodox attainment of fame and rank is inseparable from a track record of accomplishments, just like sundials are inseparable from the shadows they cast, and a person's yell is inseparable from the echoes that follow.

From Records of the Grand Historian:

《史記・司馬穰苴列傳》
穰苴先馳至軍，立表下漏待賈。
Sima Rangju arrived to the army encampment with haste, and erected sundials and water clocks, waiting for Zhuang Jia.

